# Как распознать направление движение касания пальца touch с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как распознать вертикальное направление движение касания пальца вверх или вниз на мобильных устройствах при прокрутке страницы с помощью javascript(Jquery)? Методы на базе событий scroll,к сожалению, работают некорректно при скрытии и показа блоков. Нужен метод на базе touch. нижеприведенный код работает лишь отчасти почему-то при втором касании к экрану:

```
$(window).on('touchstart', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; // первая точка прикосновения
    starty = parseInt(touchobj.clientY); // положение точки касания по y, относительно левого края браузера
    e.preventDefault();
            $(window).on('touchmove', function(event){
            var touchobj = event.changedTouches[0]; // первая точка прикосновения для данного события
            var dist = parseInt(touchobj.clientY) - starty;
            if(dist>0){
                        jQuery('#btn_mobile').css('opacity', '1');
                        jQuery('#btn_mobile').css('z-index', '9999');
                    }
                    else{
                        jQuery('#btn_mobile').css('opacity', '0');
                        jQuery('#btn_mobile').css('z-index', '0');
                    }
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: Может это поможет (https://codepen.io/ganmahmud/pen/RaoKZa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- на `touchstart` устанавливаем переменную в `true`
- на `touchmove`, ЕСЛИ переменяя `true`, делаем все что нужно
- на `touchend` устанавливаем переменную в `false`

Для определения направления, в `touchstart` сохраняем координаты начала движения, а в `touchmove` вычисляем уже относительно них

```
let event = null;

document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
    event = e;
});
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
    if (event) {
        console.log("Move delta: " + (e.touches[0].pageY - event.touches[0].pageY))
    }
});
document.addEventListener("touched", function (e) {
    event = null;
});
```

Вот аналог для mousemove, просто чтобы могли посмотреть прямо здесь):

```js
var event = null;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    event = e;
});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (event) {
        console.log("Move delta: " + (e.screenY - event.screenY))
    }
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    event = null;
});
```

Comment: Переменная не будет видна вне функции touchstart и потом мне нужно направление определить

Comment: Если переменную объявить в глобальном пространстве, все будет видно @artur-han

Comment: А направление все равно не определить вашим способом

Comment: Обновил ответ. Именно таким способом я сам определяю направление и степень смещения